# QObject::findChild returns wrong address when used with a custom widget plugin

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia

When I call QObject::findChildren(), the address I receive is not the right address but it points to an exact copy of what im looking for. This error happens for the only case where im trying to find a custom widget plugin I have created.  Whats up with that...do i need to add something to the plugin project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it probably because you have called setupUi twice.